# Dropdown sum powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, dropdown, powerapp, formula

I would like to make a sum of all dropdown values into a label text box.

I am using following formula, but I do not understand where am I going wrong.

Can anyone assist?

I have also added a screenshot if that helps anyhow.

**Note**: `scores` is the table name the dropdown values feed from.

```
Sum(scores, Dropdown3.Selected.Value + Dropdown3_1.Selected.Value + Dropdown3_2.Selected.Value)
```

[image: Snapshot of my app]

Comment: What is the error message you get on label control?

Comment: Ganesh, formula is invalid. Error persists. Name isn't valid. This identifier isn't recognized.

Comment: Have you tried formula in answer? Can you share screenshot of error message?

Comment: Hi ganesh, yes I've tried both formulas. 

I do not think it is formula error but something else.

I have emailed a picture with error message.

Comment: I think there is issue with the drop-down controls in your form or in SharePoint connector. Try refreshing SharePoint data source, removing and re-adding dropdown controls in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Text property of label to:

```
Sum(Dropdown3.Selected.Value, Dropdown3_1.Selected.Value, Dropdown3_2.Selected.Value)
```

If data type of selected item value from drop-down is string then use:

```
Sum(Value(Dropdown3.Selected.Value), Value(Dropdown3_1.Selected.Value), Value(Dropdown3_2.Selected.Value))
```

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Sum function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-aggregates)
2. [Value function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-value)

Comment: If you want to store the value of Sum to use anywhere else then you can use [variables in power apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables).