# Dropdown Sum Power Apps

Tags: dropdown, powerapp

trying to a sum dropdown sum.
I have an error somewhere, but cannot figure it out.
Can anyone assist?
I have attached a picture with the error.
Thanks a million!
Jose[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropdown sum powerapps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287430/dropdown-sum-powerapps)

Comment: It looks like your dropdown's selected value may not have a `.Value` property. What do your items look like?

Comment: There might be issues with the drop-down controls in your form or in SharePoint connector. Try refreshing SharePoint data source, removing and re-adding dropdown controls in your form. Also, can you please add the details about the structure of data source passed to items property of dropdowns in your question?